# How to use .each properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have jQuery find the height/width attributes for the image inside the div with the class "image" and then apply those values as css to the div with the class "overlay" which is a child of "image". The code below is what i've got so far. It works great for one instance of "image". But I'm not sure how to make it go through every instance of "image" and apply the correct values to "overlay". I played around with .each but I couldn't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="some-img" width="400" height="200" />
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var height = $("img").attr("height");
var width = $("img").attr("width");

    $(".overlay").css({
        height: height,
        width: width
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this supposed to be event-driven, or on dom ready?

Comment: Why don't you make `.image` `position: relative` and `.overlay` `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 999`?

Comment: Because height:100% renders differently on different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".image").each(function(index, el) {
    var $img = $("img", this); // equivalent: $(this).find("img")
    $(".overlay", this).css({
         height: $img.attr("height"),
         width: $img.attr("width")
    });
});
```

You also could iterate over the `img` elements themselves and use `.next()` to get the respective overlay.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.image img').each(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            h = that.height(),
            w = that.width();
        that.next().css({ 'height' : h, 'width' : w });
    });
```

Comment: I think the `.height()` method does something else than getting the attribute

Comment: I think you should use `.attr("height")` because images can take some time to load; therefore calling `.height()` on document ready might give you an unexpected value (often 0 or 32px). Whether the image is in the cache or not also matters.

Comment: It might, but that rather assumes that all images will have the `height` attribute set. Which is almost never the case in my own work; if it's a problem that the images might not be loaded then `$(window).load()` should be used, rather than `$(document).ready()`.